# How to validate keys of a json in java

Tags: java, json, validation

Let's assume valid json is

```
{
  "a": "valueA",
  "b": "valueB"
}
```

Is there a neat way in java to validate the keys of json so that if the following is processed it fails with a message stating a particular key(in this case 'a1') is not a supported key/wrong key

```
{
  "a1": "valueA", //wrong key a1 instead of a
  "b": "valueB"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map this json to any java class something like:

```
class Foo{
    String a;
    String b;
}
```

& then calling :

```
Foo foo=new ObjectMapper().readValue("{ \"a1\" : \"valueA\", \"b\" : \"valueB\"}",Foo.class);
```

will give you exception as

```
Unrecognized field "a1"
```

Comment: @JsonProperty is unnecessary as long as the field names match, and `TypeReference` is unnecessary in this case. You'd use `TypeReference` when dealing with generics.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider , thanks, made edit to answer.

Comment: @AshishPatil I am already doing this. I have a class to which the json is mapped and I am also using object mapper to read the value. However it still doesn't throw any exception. What it does is it ignores the keys which are wrong and doesn't throw any error.

Comment: How you are doing it? I reproduced it & then only I posted my answer. Can you share your object mapper call, will have a look

Comment: public static Foo getFooRequestFromBody(String body, ObjectMapper mapper) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return mapper.readValue(body, Foo.class);
    }

I pass this 'body' as string. This contains the json string.

Comment: can you also post -- if possible -- your `body` argument?

Comment: sure..

as I debug it the body is:

{
  "a1": "valueA",
  "b": "valueB"
}

and it didn't throw any exception. It just accepts this.

Comment: Are you really sure, because I am not seeing any escape characters in your `body` argument.

Comment: yeah.. this is the body that I get as I debug. Is that the reason?

Comment: before passing it to `mapper.readValue`, can you print that `body` in your console & share what is being printed?

Comment: { "a1": "valueA", "b": "valueB" }  this is what gets printed before I pass it on to mapper

Comment: This looks to me is not correct String formatted json & that is reason your readValue is not throwing error. From where you are getting this `body `

Comment: Also on a side note, would be good if you upvote this answer first as this is properly working & tested.

Comment: Upvoted.
I get this body as part of another json. It is a value of a key in that json. It is in string format in that json. However as I extract it out from that json, string format is disturbed.

Comment: I do have some time, can we move discussion to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245097/discussion-between-ashish-patil-and-rahul).

Comment: yes.. in few minutes?

Comment: @AshishPatil that thing worked but I am facing the below exception now after the changes you suggested

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `Foo` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value (

Comment: Fixed. There was some other unneeded annotation